# Flash Develop : Build halted with errors (fcsh) why?

Tags: flash, flashdevelop

I try to recompile a flash package from somebody who has left the company and I have some difficulty to understand why I can't.

There are only warnings of type "variable 'x' has no type declaration" when building so why does it halt ?

Answer (score 2):

FlashDevelop treats warnings as errors and so won't compile successfully if there are warnings.

Comment: Getting rid of the warnings was the easiest solution! +1

Answer (score 1):

There could be an obscure error of which has not been picked up by the ide. these include package declaration errors, sometimes inline XML and especially Flex - mxml errors unflagged.

Try cleaning the application, ensure no SVN files a kicking around -

--

ooh I'd like to add this happened to me once when I tried to make a backup of a class called Myclass_old.as

The ide will try and parse it - bt of course I had the same thing. I guess that falls under incorrect package naming but it easy to overlook.

Comment: Well i have no svn files and no special files. But it uses fl.transitions.* classes I don't have so I decompiled some swf files to get them, maybe that's not good ?

Comment: As I remember decompliers can never get the code out perfectly - but I'm curious. If the package is 'fl.transitions' then why did you need to decompile the old work? Are they not native to flash (Due to the 'fl' package name) - Could you be implementing package namespaces that already exist?

Answer (score 1):

I went to project properties->compiler options then set Enable All Warnings to false..and it worked like a charm after.
Seems like warnings are treated as errors by default